Expense Rows per page
Currently in expense default is 50 rows per page.
How do i increase that to more than that. Example 100. Please see image.
Thanks


There is a setting in 'Administer - Custom Data & Screen - Search Preferences' that allows you to change the default pager size.

Thanks for your replay. I did set 100 Default Search Pager but still show only 50. Looks like that setting works for everything except for expense.

Looks like Expense is an extension - so you may need to dig in their code and modify
https://docs.civicrm.org/expenses/en/latest/using/
